# What would happen if a woman astronaut didn’t wear/took off her helmet/spacesuit while on the moon/mars?

Tags: science-based, environment

In this story, Mars is totally inhabited by women
Would she die from lack of oxygen/suffocation or lack of pressure/boiling fluids?

Comment: Death from lack of oxygen/suffocation and incredibly cold temperatures

Comment: How long will that exposure to space or martian atmosphere last?

Comment: Would suffocation or freezing kill her first? What about lack of pressure?

Comment: Gender is not important here.  You can use "she" as the default pronoun though.  It's a nice change.  This also seems like something that is easy to Google and/or has been asked before.

Comment: @Cyn "She" as default pronoun is something common on RPG boards since what, 10 years? It was more popular than "he" on Wizards of the Coast official D&D board when I was active there, for example. Most of my homebrew content was written that way. At the same time, it was considered kinda rude to mention gender explicitly when it was not relevant. For example, bearded dwarf women discussion? OK. Dwarf man / woman axe damage? Not OK. I guess people here have similar feelings and that's what attracts downvotes.

Comment: @Mołot 10 years? I got an "OD&D" box set in the early nineties and it was also using "she"!

Comment: @colmde I should say "at least 10 years" I guess. Earlier than that I didn't interact with english-language content that much.

Answer (score 5):

Exactly the same thing as would happen to a man.

A human can survive between 15 and 90 seconds of exposure to hard vacuum. However, this is not without consequences. Exposed skin will suffer severe damage to capillaries due to ebullism, and any moist surfaces such as the eyes will be desiccated due to evaporation of fluids.

Most importantly, if you attempt to hold your breath, the pressure of the air expanding in your lungs will cause them to rupture. If you do not have a lungful of air, suffocation will shortly follow.

One thing to note, is that you will not freeze. Vacuum is unable to conduct, nor convect heat. That leaves radiation, which humans aren't very good at. Vacuum will not cause you to lose much heat at all.

Comment: Wouldn't more evaluation cause temperatures to drop?

Comment: @MiguelBartelsman Evaluation?

Comment: Goddamned autocorrect. Wouldn't **moisture evaporation** cause temperatures to drop?

Comment: @MiguelBartelsman Yes. Evaporative cooling does occur, just not fast enough the be a problem until long after the individual in question is dead.

Answer (score 1):

She would suffocate and NO holding breath will not help. So she will have 10s-20s to get air back in her lungs or she will faint. After that you have 5 min to help her or she is dead or vegetable. After 3 min she is most likely dead from damage done.

About freezing. Yes, vacuum does not conduct heat, but your boiling fluids will take heat from your body.

Not something I would like to taste: to boil, get desiccated and freeze all that while I suffocate and feel like some parts of me want to explode(you will baloon to like twice your size) and you just vomited, deficated and urinated your soon-to-be-corpse.

[NASA data on animals.](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19660005052.pdf)

Comment: Evaporative cooling due to loss of moisture won't act fast enough to be an issue until the person is already dead.

Comment: Yeah, just needed to add as someone may save you, before your brain dies and you need to deal with that. Or just to know, what will be with your bpdy after.

Comment: No boil. Dry tongue, dry eyes and that's it. Skin gives enough pressure to hold body fluids inside you below boiling point.

Comment: Skin not so much, but it will from your lungs and gastrointestinal tract. If repressured, it will freeze over. Nasa test: https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19660005052.pdf